# Does lead lining really work against a nuclear explosion?

Tags: realism, indiana-jones, the-kingdom-of-the-crystal-skull

In Indiana Jones: Kingdom of Crystal Skull, Jones is able to escape a nuclear explosion by using a **lead lined fridge**.

I read here [What Makes Lead Good for Radiation Shielding?](http://www.canadametal.com/lead-good-for-radiation-shielding/) and was wondering if lead lining really works against nuclear explosions.

**Note:** I am not asking about the realism of the whole scene of surviving out of a dropped out fridge at high speed, only about lead lining vs nuclear explosion.

Answer (score 8):

[Obviously not](http://newsfeed.time.com/2012/02/28/indiana-jones-nuke-the-fridge-plot-is-shockingly-scientifically-impossible/):

> In response to this claim, a civic-minded scientist has subjected the
>   stunt to the rigors of scientific peer review and [posted the results
>   on Overthinking It](https://www.overthinkingit.com/2012/02/22/fridge-nuking-scientific-peer-review/?page=all), a blog with a tagline of “where we subject the
>   popular culture to a level of scrutiny it probably doesn’t deserve.”
>   After a careful and extremely thorough crunching of the numbers
>   comparing drag, wind resistance, the energy and force of an atomic
>   bomb blast versus a solid Frigidaire, Dr. David Shechner concluded
>   that, sadly, **it just wasn’t possible**. Then he goes ahead and lists all
>   the ways that beloved hero and professor of archaeology Indiana Jones
>   would perish in the blast. In short, sorry George Lucas, but it’s back
>   to digging the bomb shelter in the basement.

The [linked blog](https://www.overthinkingit.com/2012/02/22/fridge-nuking-scientific-peer-review/?page=all) delves into the protection lead would provide, and how the lead would actually be an issue itself:

> Implicit in their implementation of this sequence is the authors’
>   belief that Indy’s survival is dependent on his encasement within the
>   lead-lined refrigerator.  However, this device itself may present
>   additional dangers beyond those directly related to the atomic blast. 
>   To wit, the melting  temperature of lead is a paltry 327.46°C,
>   potentially below the external temperature.  Now, liquifying lead
>   requires enough energy to overcome its heat of fusion, and the time
>   required to impart this energy. Observing the clip, we can only
>   conclude that the air temperature exceeds lead’s melting temperature
>   for a fraction of a second (and likely never reaches stainless steel’s
>   melting temperature of >1500°C) though the ensuing nuclear furnace is
>   probably warmer than a balmy Nevada afternoon.  Temperatures near
>   ground zero of the Hiroshima blast, for example, incinerated
>   essentially any object that could be burned; the ensuing fireball
>   ignited and consumed a substantially larger area. Hence, while it
>   seems unlikely that Indy would find himself drowning in a pool of
>   molten lead, **it’s highly likely that the integrity of the lead lining
>   would become severely compromised.**

With regard to the shielding by lead:

> He is, however, encased in a lead-lined refrigerator, which would
>   provide some shielding from the massive onslaught of radioactivity.
>   However, the efficacy of this shielding is questionable, since (1)
>   **lead shielding is all but useless against neutron radiation,
>   potentially a substantial component of the radioactive flux**, (2) **the
>   shielding’s effectiveness is proportional to its thickness**: a full
>   centimeter is required to reduce gamma radiation to half its initial
>   intensity, ~3.3 cm are required to reduce it to 10% the initial flux
>   and ~6.6 cm are required to drop the flux below 1% [Note the corrected
>   math – see the comments section for this calculation.  Thanks, Bunsen!
>   -Ed], and (3) **much of the lead shielding has probably been converted into a molten pool slogging inside the ‘fridge’s lining anyway** (see
>   above). **Even if Indy manages to avoid receiving the acute lethal dose,
>   he’ll almost certainly experience a host of perfectly horrific
>   alternative effects.**